# How to send messages to multiple user and ping users stomp

Tags: java, spring, websocket, message-queue, stomp

How can i ping active users with stomp in spring project? 
i have searched for 2 days already but this code is not working 
the client script  :

```
var socket = new SockJS('/connect');   
stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
stompClient.subscribe('/topic/active', function(activeMembers) {
        console.log(activeMembers);
        showActive(activeMembers);
    });
```

here are spring configuration :

```
 <websocket:message-broker application-destination-prefix="/chat">
    <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/connect, /activeUsers">
        <websocket:handshake-interceptors>
            <bean class="uz.mirworldstyle.sensation.component.MessagingHandshakeInterceptor"/>
        </websocket:handshake-interceptors>
        <websocket:sockjs/>
    </websocket:stomp-endpoint>
    <websocket:simple-broker prefix="/topic, /queue"/>
</websocket:message-broker>
```

here is java class that:

```
@Service
public class ActiveUserPinger {

@Autowired
private MessagingController messagingController;

@Autowired
MessageSendingOperations<String> stringMessageSendingOperations;

@Autowired
private ActiveUserService activeUserService;

@Autowired
private SimpMessagingTemplate template;


@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 2000)
public void pingUsers() {
    Set<Integer> activeUsers = activeUserService.getActiveUsers();

    template.convertAndSend("/topic/active", activeUsers);
    stringMessageSendingOperations.convertAndSend("/topic/active", activeUsers);
}
}
```